# How to bind data to Picker inside ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin forms and my app has a list of items as a list view and each list item need to have a Picker. How do I bind data to the Picker controllers? Is there a way to access the child items inside a list view?

Answer (score -2):

Just define your data template for the list view as normal (there are a lot of examples for this on the web), then inside the item template bind the desired item to a picker control (also a lot of examples out there).

There shouldn't be anything special about it.

Comment: I am using XAML to create my view. I could not find a way to Bind data to the pickers in each listview item. Therefore I defined a custom Bindable Picker controller. [https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30801/xamarin-forms-bindable-picker](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30801/xamarin-forms-bindable-picker)

Comment: This is coming in the 2.3.4 release of Xamarin Forms, Picker will have an ItemsSource.

Comment: hi all
I am also facing the same issue
like I am not able to bind the picker with list view. Please help